Chrome Extension - Force Auto Update
I've been developing a Chrome Extension using Manifest V3 and need to ensure my backend stays synced with the Chrome Extension version. To achieve this, I use a backend version endpoint, which I call at certain points during the app's lifecycle. If the server version differs from the client version (if (serverVersion !== clientVersion)), I then call chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck().
The intention is for chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener() to trigger faster. This approach has been working without issues for a couple of months. However, it has recently stopped working, even in a very simple Chrome Extension I developed for testing this approach.
Here is the relevant code for better understanding:
// hello.html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Extensions</h1>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

// popup.js
async function fetchFakeServerVersion() {
  console.log("Starting fake fetch request to get the current version from the server...");

  // Simulating a delay to mimic network latency
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

  const fakeResponse = {
    result: "1.2",
    targetUrl: null,
    success: true,
    error: null,
    unAuthorizedRequest: false,
    __abp: true,
  };

  console.log("Fake fetch request completed.");
  console.log("Response JSON parsed:", fakeResponse);

  return fakeResponse.result;
}

function setupUpdateListener() {
  chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener((details) => {
    console.log("Update available details:", details);
    alert("UPDATE AVAILABLE!!");
  });
}

async function checkVersion() {
  if (!chrome?.runtime) {
    console.log("Chrome runtime is not available.");
    return;
  }

  setupUpdateListener();

  const serverVersion = await fetchFakeServerVersion();
  if (!serverVersion) {
    console.log("Could not retrieve the server version.");
    return;
  }

  const clientVersion = chrome.runtime.getManifest()?.version;
  console.log("Client version from manifest:", clientVersion);

  if (serverVersion !== clientVersion) {
    console.log("Versions do not match. Requesting update check...");
    chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck((status) => {
      console.log(`Update check status: ${status}`);
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Versions match. No update needed.");
  }
}

// Call the function to execute the version check
checkVersion();


From what I can see, the issue is that requestUpdateCheck is returning throttled, preventing onUpdateAvailable from triggering. According to Google’s documentation, throttled means repeated checks within a short period can cause this. However, this occurs even when I request an update check just once, and it keeps returning throttled for hours until it eventually updates.
Does anyone have any insights into this issue? What could be the possible causes, solutions, or workarounds?

Sounds like a bug in the browser that is stuck in the throttled state. Try removing the extension to clear the state, then install it again.
